# cloneElement: Type has no properties in common with type Partial<P> & Attributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, definitelytyped

In code similar to the following, I'm getting `Type { foo: number } has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Child> & Attributes'` for the second parameter of the call to `cloneElement` and I don't understand why... It appears to me that `Partial<Child>` is getting props of the right shape, but TypeScript doesn't agree.

Here's the library versions from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

```
"@types/react": "16.3.14",
"@types/react-dom": "16.0.5",
```

Here's the example:

```
import * as React from "react";
interface Props {
  foo: number;
}
class Child extends React.Component<Props> {
    public render(): React.ReactNode {
        return <span>{this.props.foo}</span>;
    }
}
class Parent extends React.Component<Props> {
    public render(): React.ReactNode {
        return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child: JSX.Element) => this.cloneChild(child));
    }

    public cloneChild(child: React.ReactElement<Child>): React.ReactElement<Child> {
        const newProps = {
            foo: this.props.foo,
        };
        return React.cloneElement<Child>(child, newProps);
    }
}
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type parameters to `ReactElement` and `cloneElement` denote the type of the props rather than the component, so you probably intended this:

```
public cloneChild(child: React.ReactElement<Props>): React.ReactElement<Props> {
    const newProps = {
        foo: this.props.foo,
    };
    return React.cloneElement<Props>(child, newProps);
}
```

or, equivalently,

```
public cloneChild(child: React.ReactElement<Props>) {
    const newProps = {
        foo: this.props.foo,
    };
    return React.cloneElement(child, newProps);
}
```

Also, there's an incorrect typecast `(child: JSX.Element)`. The type for `child` in `React.Children.map` is `ReactChild` (which boils down to `ReactElement<any> | string | number`,) and by casting to `JSX.Element` (== `ReactElement<any>`), you don't take into account possible string or number children. Since `cloneElement` fails on `string` or `number` children, the current code gives a runtime error if you include for example a text element: `<Parent>x<Child/></Parent>`.

To get rid of the type error without casting, you can check for `string` and `number` like this:

```
public render() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) =>
      typeof child === 'number' || typeof child === 'string'
      ? child
      : this.cloneChild(child)
    );
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'd missed that because the old `ReactElement` and `cloneElement` definitions took the `Child` type just fine... looks like whoever wrote this code was using it wrong anyway and it broke when I upgraded the types definitions.